# Left Join Sql consultas

Tags: sql, sql-server

trato de hacer una subconsulta en sql services donde tengo 2 tablas, una con eventos y otra con la fecha de estos, se me pide que en la consulta traiga los eventos actuales y que los que no tengan eventos se muestren en null, ahí es donde utilizo el Left Join, pero por alguna razón, solo me trae la tabla de eventos, alguna idea de que pueda hacer?

Mis dos tablas son las siguientes
Esta es la tabla camaras, donde aquí agrego los eventos, en este caso encesito que se muestre la camara 5 que es la que no posee eventos
[image: Esta es la tabla camaras, donde aquí agrego los eventos, en este caso encesito que se muestre la camara 5 que es la que no posee eventos]

Esta es la tabla eventos

[image]

Cuando llamo a la tabla de camaras para el id numero 5 lo hago de esta manera

```
Select * From camaras ca
left Join eventos ev1
ON  ev1.id_camara =  ca.id_camara
Where ev1.Fecha_imagen_utc = (select max(Fecha_imagen_utc) 
        From eventos ev2 where ev1.Id=ev2.Id)
```

Pero solo me trae los ids 1, 2 y 4, no me trae el 5 que es donde no hay eventos y eso es lo que trato de hacer con el Inner Join, alguna idea de que pueda hacer?

Comment: En la tabla Camaras tienes "id" y también "id_camara". ¿Qué es cada uno? ¿Cuál de los dos es la clave primaria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema consiste en que estás usando una columna de la tabla Eventos en la clausula WHERE. Eso elimina automáticamente todos los valores que se encuentren como `NULL` y hace que el `LEFT JOIN` funcione como `INNER JOIN`.

Para obtener el último evento de cada cámara, puedes usar una `common table expression (cte)` junto con la función `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
WITH cteEventosCamaras AS(
    Select ca.id_camara, 
           ca.marca,
           ca.modelo,
           ev1.archivo,
           ev1.error,
           ev1.error_descripcion,
           ev1.fecha_imagen,
           ev1.fecha_imagen_utc,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ca.id_camara ORDER BY ev1.fecha_imagen_utc DESC) AS rn
    FROM camaras      AS ca
    LEFT JOIN eventos AS ev1 ON ev1.id_camara =  ca.id_camara
)
SELECT *
FROM cteEventosCamaras
WHERE rn = 1;
```